# I am getting a strange error when I try to start the playground server localy:

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

```
plutus-playground-server: for development use only
error: creating symlink from '/plutus/plutus-playground-server/result.tmp-10234-376872119' to '/nix/store/hf815gz6hs5px2nrnnvsdjcpf8m0dvwg-ghc-shell-for-packages-ghc-8.10.2.20201118-env': Permission denied
error: creating symlink from '/plutus/plutus-playground-server/result.tmp-10236-1766163927' to '/nix/store/a1g0yvyi27qjkapb04z75d5s8gf8jx6k-plutus-playground-server-exe-plutus-playground-server-0.1.0.0': Permission denied
/nix/store/rm5268gvw75mmh8mhcbb9rs817wvnfhj-plutus-playground-server/bin/plutus-playground-server: line 10: /bin/plutus-playground-server: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas? Why permission is denied and why it says No such file or directory?

Comment: I have same error error: creating symlink from... access denied

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the directory "/bin/plutus-playground-server"?

You can search in bash like:

$ls /bin/plutus-playground-server

That command should return a result/output.
→ It now result is returned the directory "/bin/plutus-playground-server" is set wrong.